# Hyperledger TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a function or null

Tags: typescript, hyperledger-fabric

I'm getting the following error when I'm attempting to instantiate chaincode for Hyperledger Fabric.

```
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dev/Documents/drc-api/dist/src/hyperledger/models/document.js:4:32)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dev/Documents/drc-api/dist/src/hyperledger/drcContract.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
```

I've checked for circular dependency with [Madge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOrQV.png), and I don't think that's the issue.

I'm using the IBM Blockchain Platform extension in VSCode to create a Hyperledger network to install and instantiate the chaincode for testing.

1. Extra info:

   - Node v8.16.1
   - NPM  v6.11.3
   - Docker v19.03.2
   - Docker-compose v1.24.1
   - Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Here are the files it's complaining about.

**drcContract.ts**

```
import { Contract, Context } from 'fabric-contract-api';
import {Document} from './models/document'
import {Case} from './models/case'    
import {DocumentList} from './lists/documentList'    
import {CaseList} from './lists/caseList'    
import {Log, Action} from './models/log'    
import { Timestamp } from 'google-protobuf/google/protobuf/timestamp_pb';

class DRCContext extends Context {
    /* functions */
}

export class DRCContract extends Contract {
    /* functions */
}
module.exports = DRCContract;
```

**document.ts**

```
import {State} from '../hyperledger-state/state';
import {Log} from './log';
import {Timestamp} from "google-protobuf/google/protobuf/timestamp_pb";

export class Document extends State {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    /* Getters & Setters */    
}    
export default Document;    
module.exports = Document;
```

**drcContract.js**

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const fabric_contract_api_1 = require("fabric-contract-api");
const document_1 = require("./models/document");
const case_1 = require("./models/case");
const documentList_1 = require("./lists/documentList");
const caseList_1 = require("./lists/caseList");
const log_1 = require("./models/log");
const timestamp_pb_1 = require("google-protobuf/google/protobuf/timestamp_pb");
class DRCContext extends fabric_contract_api_1.Context {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    /* functions */
}
class DRCContract extends fabric_contract_api_1.Contract {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    /* functions */
}
exports.DRCContract = DRCContract;
module.exports = DRCContract;
```

**document.js**

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const state_1 = require("../hyperledger-state/state");
class Document extends state_1.State {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    /* Getters & Setters */
}
exports.Document = Document;
exports.default = Document;
module.exports = Document;
```

Comment: missing an export ? eg export class DRCContext extends Context {

    constructor() {
        // etc
    }
    // functions
}

// Main Contract

export class DRCContract extends Contract {

    constructor() {
        // etc
    }
   // functions
}

Comment: Adding the export doesn't work either, it still gives the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Is it required to use Typescript Decorators when using fabric-contract-api?

Comment: what's the content of this file ? ../hyperledger-state/state ? It's likely you are trying to import State, but State has not been explicitly exported

Comment: I'm exporting State.

Comment: @Alkiimista Did you ever find a solution to this? Please post your solution.